# Is there a quick way to combine word dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Is there a quick way to combine word dictionaries(MapType) in a list?

word

[[word1 -> 2], [wor2 ->3] .... [word2 -> 4]]

--------------------------------------result-----------------------

word

[[word1 ->2] ,[wor2 -> 7]]

There is a problem that it takes a long time using the udf function.

```
def dictsum(keywords) :
    dictlist = []
    sumdict = {}

    for wordcounts in keywords :
        for k, v in wordcounts.items() :
            print(wordcounts.items())
            if k not in sumdict :
                sumdict[k] = 1
            else :
                sumdict[k] += 1

    dictlist.append(sumdict)
    return dictlist




  dict_df = noun_df.select("createDate","nounwords")
wordcountUdf = udf(wordcount, ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),IntegerType())))
dict_df = dict_df.withColumn("wordcount",wordcountUdf(dict_df['nounwords']))
#dict_df.show(100,False)

keyword_f = dict_df.select("createDate","wordcount")
keyword_f = keyword_f.groupby("createDate").agg(flatten(collect_list("wordcount")).alias("keywords"))
keyword_f = keyword_f.withColumn("statistic_type",lit("keyword_f"))
#keyword_f.show(10,False)

dictsumUdf = udf(dictsum, ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),IntegerType())))
keyword_f = keyword_f.withColumn("wordcounts",dictsumUdf(keyword_f['keywords']))
keyword_f = keyword_f.drop("keywords")
#keyword_f.show(100,False)
```

Comment: There is no clue that you are using the spark, so I deleted the tag and added the python.

Comment: Since my answer is now useless, so I deleted it. Please specify your problem with the reproducible data. I cannot test your case.